# Pine Editor TradingView Problem: Set Stop Loss and TP for EMA crossover strategy

Tags: pine-script

sorry. I am new to Pine script editor, so it will be great if anyone can help me figure this out.

I am trying to do a strategy that go long and short based on 50 EMA and 200 EMA crossover, with a set stop loss and take profit.

The strategy will go long when 50 EMA crosses above 200 EMA, with TP set at 2% and 3% and SL at 1.25%

It will go short when 50 EMA crosses below 200 EMA, with TP1 set at 2%, TP2 set at 3% and SL ar 1.25%.

However, Tradingview gives me the following error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU85h.png

```html
        /@version=4
strategy(title="Take profit (% of instrument price)", overlay=true, pyramiding=1)

// STEP 1:
// Make inputs that set the take profit % (optional)

FastPeriod = input(title="Fast MA Period", type=input.integer, defval=50, minval=1, group="Moving Average")
SlowPeriod = input(title="Slow MA Period", type=input.integer, defval=200, minval=1, group="Moving Average")

TP1Perc = input(title="Long Take Profit (%)", type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=2, group="TP & SL") 
TP2Perc = input(title="Long Take Profit (%)", type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=3, group="TP & SL") 
SLPerc = input(title="Long Stop Loss (%)", type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1.25, group="TP & SL")

TP1_Ratio = input(title="Sell Postion Size % @ TP1", type=input.float, defval=50, step=1, group="TP & SL", tooltip="Example: 50 closing 50% of the position once TP1 is reached")/100


// Calculate moving averages
fastEMA = ema(close, FastPeriod)
slowEMA = ema(close, SlowPeriod)

// Calculate trading conditions
enterLong  = crossover(fastEMA, slowEMA)
entershort = crossover(slowEMA,fastEMA)

// Plot moving averages
plot(series=fastEMA, color=color.green, title="Fase MA")
plot(series=slowEMA, color=color.red, title="Slow MA")

// STEP 2:
// Figure out take profit price
percentAsPoints(pcnt) =>
    strategy.position_size != 0 ? round(pcnt / 100.0 * strategy.position_avg_price / syminfo.mintick) : float(na)

percentAsPrice(pcnt) =>
    strategy.position_size != 0 ? ((pcnt / 100.0) + 1.0) * strategy.position_avg_price : float(na)
 
current_position_size = abs(strategy.position_size)
initial_position_size = abs(valuewhen(strategy.position_size[1] == 0.0, strategy.position_size, 0))   
    
TP1  = strategy.position_avg_price + percentAsPoints(TP1Perc) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / abs(strategy.position_size)
TP2  = strategy.position_avg_price + percentAsPoints(TP2Perc) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / abs(strategy.position_size)
SL   = strategy.position_avg_price - percentAsPoints(SLPerc) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / abs(strategy.position_size)
STP1  = strategy.position_avg_price - percentAsPoints(TP1Perc) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / abs(strategy.position_size)
STP2  = strategy.position_avg_price - percentAsPoints(TP2Perc) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / abs(strategy.position_size)
SSL   = strategy.position_avg_price + percentAsPoints(SLPerc) * syminfo.mintick * strategy.position_size / abs(strategy.position_size)


// Submit long entry orders
if (enterLong) 
    strategy.entry(id="Long", long=true)  

// STEP 3:
// Submit exit orders based on take profit price

if strategy.position_size > 0 
    strategy.exit("TP1", from_entry="Long", qty = initial_position_size * TP1_Ratio, limit = TP1, stop = SL)
    strategy.exit("TP2", from_entry="Long", limit = TP2, stop = SL) 
    
    
// Plot take profit values for confirmation
plot(series=(strategy.position_size > 0) ? TP1 : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, title="Take Profit 1")
plot(series=(strategy.position_size > 0) ? TP2 : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, title=" Take Profit 2")
plot(series=(strategy.position_size > 0) ? SL : na, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, title="Stop Loss")

// Submit short entry orders
if (entershort) 
    strategy.entry(id="short", long=false) 
    
if strategy.position_size > 0 
    strategy.exit("TP1", from_entry="short", qty = initial_position_size * STP1_Ratio, limit = STP1, stop = SSL)
    strategy.exit("TP2", from_entry="short", limit = STP2, stop = SSL) 
    
    
// Plot take profit values for confirmation
plot(series=(strategy.position_size > 0) ? STP1 : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, title="Short TP 1")
plot(series=(strategy.position_size > 0) ? STP2 : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, title="Short TP 2")
plot(series=(strategy.position_size > 0) ? SSL : na, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=1, title="Short Stop Loss")
```

What am I doing wrong, can anyone please help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The version declaration at the beginning should have 2 slashes, rather than 1 and some tabs. example:

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="Take profit (% of instrument price)", overlay=true, pyramiding=1)
```

That will get you by the first error, and produce another undeclared identifier STP1_Ratio, which you have not included in this code.

Cheers and best of luck!